# How to check object's type inside Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a class `Employee` which derives from `Person`. I list them on index page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How to check if item is `Employee` xor `Person` inside this loop?

For instance:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
          @if(**item is Employee**){
              @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "EmployeeController", new { id = item.Id},null)
           }else{
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details","PersonController", new { id=item.Id }, null) 
          }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
@if (item.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Employee))
{
    //item is of type Employee
}
```

Update: I might have misread your *"How to check if item is Employee xor Person inside this loop?"* question.

A `XOR`, by definition, must test both values. Why would you need to do that? If an object is an `Employee`, then he is also (by your definition) a `Person`. Your flow of `"If he's an Employee, pass it to EmployeeController. Else, pass it to PersonController"` should work, since it's evaluating if `item` is an `Employee` first (the other way around would be a problem).

The logical and conditional operators for testing one vs both sides are:

- `&` (`logical AND`) will test both values
- `&&` (`conditional AND`) will test the second value `iff` the first value is `true`
- `|` (`logical OR`) will test both values
- `||` (`conditional OR`) will test the second value `iff` the first value is `false`

Comment: Thanks, by xor I meant: `if(){}else{}` xor in C#(Java for sure) is   `^`.

Comment: Probably everything works fine now, I'll accept the answer on next weekend when I check your solution and I'll be totally sure. Thank you : ).